# No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName' when provisioning

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios-provisioning

I've just enrolled in Apple's iOS Developer Program (account type: Individual).

In my Xcode organizer on my iPhone 4 device I click "Add device to provisioning portal" => Xcode asks my credentials => I enter them => I see "No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'." dialog window.

What am I missing?

Comment: I'm suffering from the same. Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Part of the process in Xcode's automated submitting of certificate requests is that it looks for a "Wildcard" app ID. If you're missing this (for some reason, it's created on some accounts automatically and not created automatically on others?), this automated process will likely fail.

To fix it, try the following:

1) "Revoke" any existing certificates you might have from within the developer portal

2) Create a new "App Id"; title it "Wildcard"; and enter only " * " (without any spaces or quotes) as the suffix.

3) Try the automated certificate request from within Xcode again, and it should now work

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks! This process allowed me to create a new provisioning profile and register an unlocked iPhone 5 as a developer device. One addendum to the answer I discovered. When building a debug app for the registered device, my old code signing cert was still in my local keychain. The build failed with the message that "there can be only one." I deleted the older (revoked in the portal) certificate from Keychain Access and rebuilt. Success! I guess Apple's revocation infrastructure doesn't revoke certificates locally.

Comment: This worked for me without having to "Revoke" any existing certificates. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm getting the same issue in Xcode. I think it's related to the wildcard app ID that Xcode creates for you. There seems to be an issue with that process that then cancels the device addition process that you're trying to complete.

You should still be able to add the device via the [iOS Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/ios/index.action). Once logged in, go to the Provisioning Portal and you can add the device there.

Not perfect I know, but should allow you to start building apps and testing on your device until the Xcode issue is resolved.

Answer (score 5):

You could avoid this problem by making App ID with wild-card id in iOS dev center.

I guess Organizer could not follow the updated policy related to App ID in iOS Dev Center/Provisioning Portal.

App ID with wild-card("*") is seems to be restricted in some function, 
for example, Push Notification, Game Center.
and
developer also seems to be required to make sure the security option for the app related to the App ID.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, my initial goal was to be able to test my app on iPhone device. Clicking "Add device to provisioning portal" still results into the subject error, but anyway my iPhone device have been added somehow to the Provisioning Portal and now I can see my app on iPhone (I haven't even tried to add it via iOS Dev Center). My guess is that this procedure takes multiple steps to be completed, and only the last of them still fails now, while the rest of them do succeed.

Comment: Is there anybody here, who knows how to write a report to Apple about this problem? Or do we do something wrong if we see the subject error?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the provisioning profile for that application was **invalid**, then I did the following steps:

1. Login on Developers Portal
2. Click on Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles section.
3. Go to Provisioning Profiles, in the list I realized **my app profile
   was invalid**.
4. Click to **edit** it and selected the corresponding certificates (all)
   and devices (all).
5. Download the profile and un Run. Issue solved.