# No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'

Tags: ios, provisioning

Whenever I try to do anything with provisioning, adding devices to the portal, etc. get this error msg:

`No value was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.`

I have seen this post: 
[No value was provided for the paramenter 'appIdName' when provisioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884434/no-value-was-provided-for-the-parameter-appidname-when-provisioning)

however this does not apply as I have followed the instructions without any success. I must create my Team Provisioning Profile manually (and any others as well) for anything to work.  This is a pain and even adding a device throws this error. Any idea what is going on? Is this a common issue for others developing in iOS?  I've been working in iOS for 4 years now and never ran into something like this.

My profile was set to expire. I hit renew, and got this error, followed the above article with nothing helping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been having the same problem for days. I followed the instructions in the other post ([No value was provided for the paramenter 'appIdName' when provisioning)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884434/no-value-was-provided-for-the-parameter-appidname-when-provisioning) with no luck. Here is what worked for me:

open keychain access
select "login" from the keychain category
select "My Certificate" from category

Delete all your certificates associated with the provisioning profile.

What I also did is clean up everything in my provisioning portal. I revoked all certificates (distribution and Development) and all provisioning profiles.

Open up organizer in Xcode, select provisioning profiles in the top left, and click refresh.

Follow the instructions to create new profiles and certificates.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I ended up doing basically the same thing.. I removed all certificates and profiles from keychain, the provisioning portal online, and in xcode. I then tried to use XCode to create a new profile. This DID NOT work BUT i was able to get XCode to create a new development certificate for me (CSR). I then created a new App ID Wildcard/team id/* for the suffix. I then had to manually create a Team Provisioning Profile. I chose to do this from within xCode by clicking Add under profiles. This got me back to developing on devices. I still get the error when clicking refersh and with adding new device

Comment: *devices, but it doesn't affect anything so far.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as well and what worked for me was to follow the instructions here:
https://developer.apple.com/ios/manage/overview/index.action

And then launch the assistant.  These steps seem more current than the ones that described here:

[Manage Your Workflow in Xcode - Test Your App on an iOS Device](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/chapters/CreateYourAppinXcode/StartYourProjectinXcode/StartYourProjectinXcode.html)

Hopefully this will help out others.