# An "invalid value" being provided for the parameter 'appIdName'?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've been working on this app for several weeks, and everything's been great.  I've been building and archiving and having a ball.  All certificates and profiles and IDs have (seemingly) been in order and working well.

Then a few days ago, seemingly without any change that I can discern, Xcode said I didn't have any "provisioning profiles with a valid signing identity", and when I told it to "fix issue" I would get this error every time:

```
An invalid value 'Xcode: Wildcard AppID' was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.
```

I've found [a few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884434/no-value-was-provided-for-the-parameter-appidname-when-provisioning) questions that [seem similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13392307/no-value-was-provided-for-the-parameter-appidname), but I can't find anything at all about this error specifically.  Google, SO, nothing.  I do have an AppID in the Developer Portal called "Xcode: Wildcard AppID" with an ID of `*`, and I've tried making another (as suggested in those other questions) but it hasn't helped.

Can anyone explain what this error means, and how I might go about fixing it?  And for bonus points, what caused it so I can avoid this in the future?

Comment: Did you try to archive an iOS project? And did you try to distribute it in an "Ad Hoc" way? This same thing is happening to me and the only thing I can think of that I did differently than normal was archive an iOS project and attempt an "Ad Hoc" distribution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I was able to get it working. I tried what [Cirec Beback](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4305146/cirec-beback) suggested, but here are more specific instructions:

1. Go to the [Apple Developer Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/), and sign in
2. Go to your "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles"
3. Under "iOS Apps", select "Provisioning Profiles"
4. Near the top, in the "iOS Provisioning Profiles" header, hit the + button
5. Select "iOS App Development" and hit Continue
6. From the dropdown, select your "Xcode: Wildcard AppID" option and hit Continue
7. Select your user, or everybody, and hit Continue
8. Select whatever devices you want, I did all of them, and hit Continue
9. Give the Provisioning Profile a name, and hit Continue
10. The next screen will have instructions, but basically it will have a download link, so download the provisioning profile, and open it. Then you should be all good!

Comment: This solved my issue with an app for Mac OS. Follow the same steps, just pick the Mac options in the Apple Developer Member Center where possible.

Answer (score 6):

This may happen if you do not have an updated provisioning profile.

### **To fix..**

1. Go to Xcode preferences.
2. From the top tab select Accounts.
3. Click View Details button(Bottom right).
4. A screen will open showing all the provisioning profiles. Click the
   refresh button (Bottom left) and wait the refresh to finish.
5. Check your bundle identifier(General tab) and your provisioning
   profile(Build Settings).
6. Clean build.

Answer (score 6):

Another explanation for this error message is that your app bundle id contains an unsupported character such as an underscore.

Comment: This was my case. Underscore is invalid in bundle id.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this today (which is why I'm here). In my case, it was just because the build settings had the wrong Code Signing Identity and Provisioning Profile. It had nothing to do with the XCode wildcard.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem or explain steps to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The issue for me was that I had an existing app, with an existing appID, that did not have App Groups enabled. This was warned not just in capabilities, but also when I selected my main app target and viewed the Identity section.

1. I went to developer.apple.com > Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles > Identifiers
2. In Identifiers > App IDs: Selected my App ID
3. Clicked Edit, and enabled App Group under application services

Then went back to XCode and refreshed the Target General. Then back to Capabilities and let it "fix" it.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to let you know I had the same issue today. Might be an Apple issue. Anyway, I was able to go out to developer.apple.com and create the provisioning profile the old fashion way. xCode picked it up and was able to use it without any further issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was having about the same issue on an Ionic project:

```
An invalid value '-widget-id--com.myapp.main--version--0.1.19--xmlns--http---www.w3.org-ns-widgets--xmlns-android--http---schemas.android.com-apk-res-android--xmlns-cdv--http---cordova.apache.org-ns-1.0---com.myapp.main' was provided for the parameter 'appIdentifierString'.
An invalid value 'XC -widget-id--com myapp main--version--0 1 19--xmlns--http---www w3 org-ns-widgets--xmlns-android--http---schemas android com-apk-res-android--xmlns-cdv--http---cordova apache org-ns-1 0---com myapp main' was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'.
```

After looking for awhile, I figured out that my `platform/ios/MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` has it `PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER` filled with

```
-widget-id--com.myapp.main--version--0.1.19--xmlns--http---www.w3.org-ns-widgets--xmlns-android--http---schemas.android.com-apk-res-android--xmlns-cdv--http---cordova.apache.org-ns-1.0---com.myapp.main
```

I have no idea on how it happened but putting `com.myapp.main` fixed it!