# An invalid value 'io.ionic.starter' was provided for the parameter 'appIdName'

Tags: xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using cordova & Ionic to create an app and just wanted to test it out on my IOS device.
I followed every single instructions of [Ionic doc about deployment](https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/deploying/) 
and at the step of signin my app I get this error from Xcode:
[image]

At first I got the error but with 'io.ionic.starter' instead of the red mark I did, so I changed the config.xml of my project:

```
<widget id="Here I've changed the id" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

[This question has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046246/an-invalid-value-being-provided-for-the-parameter-appidname) but the solution can't help, I guess it is deprecated because the apple developper website doesn't show any "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" part.

Need help please

Comment: after changing the id, did you run `ionic cordova prepare`?

Comment: Just did and don't work